# "Google workspace private Addon icon" is not displayed in the "google side panel" after installing the deployed addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I recently deployed a google workspace add on. (its a private add on.)
From the screenshot we can see uninstall is displayed, which means the add on is installed on my browser right now.
After installing the add on, the icon is not displayed in the right hand side, side panel.
[installed plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oImnp.jpg)

Comment: Can you confirm you explicitly set that the add on can be accessed from Calendar? How does your manifest file look like? How did you deploy the add-on?

Comment: There is no option to deploy add in specifically for calendar, however there is option to deploy for sheets, slides and docs. So, in the google cloud console, i selected the workspace add on option. Also there are two options to deploy either the google cloud project deployment or the app deployment, i went for the app deployment. I selected deploy > add on option and used that deployment id in the provider for google workspace deployment, if it does not make sense i can add screenshots.

Comment: How does your manifest file look like?

Comment: The plugin is under review [extra info] My manifest file does not have anything extra, {
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
} Should i add the json that is found on this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will have to specify in the add-on manifest which Workspace application is your add-on extending.**

A detailed example of an add-on manifest file can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons).

Therefore, since you want to adjust your add-on specifically such that it is a Calendar add-on, you will have to add the [`calendar`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons) field in your manifest file.

After adding the field, the manifest will end up looking something similar to this:

```
{
   "timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata",
   "dependencies":{
      
   },
   "exceptionLogging":"STACKDRIVER",
   "runtimeVersion":"V8",
   "addOns":{
      "calendar":{
         "homepageTrigger":{
            "runFunction":"NAME_OF_THE_FUNCTION_TO_RUN"
         }
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

#### Reference

- [AddOns manifest resource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons).

Comment: "runFunction":"NAME_OF_THE_FUNCTION_TO_RUN" this is what i was missing. Thank you. I have made progress, i need to make some changes in code.